# Firebase Getting the Key of a Child

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I have a Firebase database messaging app with a database structure similar to

```
chat
-3C1
 -KdC47QwOZGlxEomFe7Q
  -name: "john"
  -text: "hello"
  -upvote: 0
```

When a person enters a message and presses send the message is uploaded to the database like this. **My question is** how do I get the key KdC47QwOZGlxEomFe7Q in code so that I can reference that exact message to update the upvote count on a button press?

Comment: What is 3C1, is that constant value or random value

Comment: @Rasi Constant value, it's the name of a chat room

Comment: So you go through all chatrooms and create HashMap with -(KdC47QwOZGlxEomFe7Q) as a key and save other data in values.

Comment: @Rasi Firebase generated that key for me, so is there no simpler way of retrieving it?

Comment: Isn't it a simpler way? Looping through all messages when you enter in a chatroom?

Comment: @Rasi I would have thought Firebase would have a method that retrieves the key. Maybe there isn't enough context here. I have a custom class containing the message data. That custom class is pushed to the Firebase database. Firebase in the background has created a key for each message entry. This is the key I would like to access. Thank you for your input, maybe your suggestion is the easiest way. I have no doubt it will work but I know that there is a getKey method in the Firebase API I'm just not sure how to use it.

Comment: You can get that key, after pushing/uploading data. I can help you with that.

Comment: You can use a Firebase Database query to get nodes based on the value of one of the child properties. But it depends a bit on what you're trying to do, which is unclear. What are you trying to accomplish here? Are you trying to display a list of the chat messages?

Comment: @FrankvanPuffelen Hi Frank, yes the functionality of the app is this. A user logs into the app then selects from a list of chatrooms (3C1 in the example). There is then a list view of messages (contained inside adapters) which are stored on the Firebase database. I can edit my post tomorrow afternoon with some code if it would make it easier to understand exactly what I'm looking for?

Answer (score 1):

Create a `DatabaseReference` on which you going to save your data.

```
 final DatabaseReference databaseRef = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference()
                                      .child("Feedback").child("data").push();

 // Here you can get node(key reference) on which your feedback going to push/save
 final String referenceKey = databaseRef.getKey();
```